# How to count the number of occurrences in a list in lisp

Tags: count, lisp, common-lisp, sublist

The assignment is

> count-of (symbol list)
>   Write a function named count-of that takes two
>   parameters, a symbol and a list. Count the number of instances of x in
>   the list. Do not count the number of x in any sub-lists within the
>   list.

I can't figure out how to skip over the sublist in the test list. He is using letters not numbers so I can't use `numberp`, and when I just have one letter I can't use `list-length`.  Also I am not sure I and doing the `let*` then `setf` correctly but I can't get it to work any other way.

```
(defun count-of (x list)
  (let* count 0)
  (setf count 0)
  (dolist (y list)
    (if (not a sublist) 
        (setf count (+ count 1)))))

(print (count-of 'a '(a '(a c) d c a)))
```

Comment: (defun count-of ( x list)
             (let* count 0)
             (setf count 0)
             (dolist (y list)
               (if (not a sublist)
                   (setf count (+ count 1))
               )
             )
           )

(print (count-of 'a '(a '(a c) d c a)))

Comment: The question is imperfectly specified. In Lisp, `NIL` is both a symbol and a list. The notations `()` and `NIL` mean the same thing. When the function is asked to count the occurrences of `NIL` in the list `(A B () C)`, should it report zero because it's skipping the inner list `NIL` , or should it report 1 because `(A B () C)` is really `(A B NIL C)`, where we regard `NIL` as a symbol to be counted?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure out how to skip over the sublist in the test list.

In order to check the sublists, you would have to do *more* work, so the assignment is in fact asking you to keep it simple. Consider that you can compare values non-recursively with [`EQL`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm):

```
(eql 'a 'b) => NIL
(eql 'a 'a) => T
```

But `eql` is not restricted to symbols nor numbers, you can pass any object and it will return NIL when two values are not trivially equal.

```
(eql '(a b c) 'a) => NIL
```

In other words, you increment your counter when you find a match with `eql`, and that's it.

> He is using letters not numbers so I can't use numberp, and when I just have one letter I can't use list-length.

If you want to distinguish between symbols and lists, there are predicates you can use, like `atom` or `consp`, or even `typecase` (see [14.2 The Conses Dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_conses.htm)).

> Also I am not sure I and doing the let* then setf correctly but I can't get it to work any other way.

You are indeed using `let` wrong; [`LET`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm) introduces variables around a body, for example:

```
(let ((x 10)
      (y 20))
  (+ x y))
```

So you would need to do:

```
(let ((count 0))
  (dolist (x list count)
    ...))
```

Note that [`DOLIST`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dolist.htm) admits a third parameter that is a form that will be evaluated at the end of the loop. Inside the loop, you can `setf` count as you want (see also `incf`).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than giving you an answer which will just help you hand in your homework without thinking, I'll try to give one that will help you think about the problem, and other similar problems, like a Lisp hacker.

To this end, think about an algorithm for solving this problem:

If we're know how many occurrences of the thing we are looking for are in the list so far, then:

- if the list is empty, then the answer is the number we've seen so far;
- otherwise the list is not empty, and –

  - if the first element of the list is the same as the thing we are counting, then the answer is the number of occurences in the rest of the list, assuming we have seen one more than we had previously seen;
  - if the first element of the list is *not* the same as the thing we are counting, then the answer is the number of occurences in the rest of the list, assuming we've seen the same number we've already seen.

And that's it.  Well, we can turn this into code very easily: it's pretty obviously the specification of a recursive function, with a base-case for the recursion when the list is empty.  But to make things more interesting we'll heavily restrict the parts of the language we can use.  In particular, in the body of the definition:

- the function is not allowed to know its own name;
- the only variable-binding consruct we can use is `lambda`.

The first trick is that how to use `lambda` for variable-binding.  Well, this is easy, because binding variables is what `lambda` does:

```
((lambda (x) ... here x is bound to 1 ...) 1)
```

The second trick is that, if the function is not allowed to know its own name, then the way it has to call itself is by being passed *itself* as one of its arguments.  So the guts of the function looks like this:

```
(lambda (c elt tail count-so-far)
  ;; Here:
  ;; - c is the function we must call to count the rest of the list
  ;;   (it's this function!);
  ;; - elt is the thing we are looking for;
  ;; - tail is the tail of the list we are searching;
  ;; - count-so-far is the count of elements found so far
  ;;
  (if (null tail)
      ;; we're done: count-so-far is the count
      count-so-far
    ;; There is more to do. eql is the appropriate 'is this the same
    ;; as that' predicate in this case.
    (if (eql elt (first tail))
        ;; we've found one, so we need to recurse with the count being one more
        (funcall c c elt (rest tail) (+ count-so-far 1))
      ;; we didn't find one
      (funcall c c elt (rest tail) count-so-far))))
```

The annoying thing about this code is that, in order to call a function, we have to do this `(funcall c c ...)` thing: the reason for this is that CL is what's called a Lisp-2, so in a form like `(f x)`, `f` is looked up in a different namespace (a different space of bindings) than `x`: `funcall` is what we have to use to say 'call the function I have bound to this variable'.  In any case we're calling whatever is bound to `c`, passing it itself as its first argument so it can in turn call itself.

Now we have to initiate the process, by binding this thing to a variable and then calling it.  We can do this using `lambda` as above.

```
((lambda (f)
   ;; kick off the recursion: at the start the count of elements seen
   ;; so far is 0.
   (funcall f f the-element list 0))
 (lambda (c elt tail count-so-far)
   ;; Here:
   ;; - c is the function we must call to count the rest of the list
   ;;   (it's this function!);
   ;; - elt is the thing we are looking for;
   ;; - tail is the tail of the list we are searching;
   ;; - count-so-far is the count of elements found so far
   ;;
   (if (null tail)
       ;; we're done: count-so-far is the count
       count-so-far
     ;; There is more to do. eql is the appropriate 'is this the same
     ;; as that' predicate in this case.
     (if (eql elt (first tail))
         ;; we've found one, so we need to recurse with the count being one more
         (funcall c c elt (rest tail) (+ count-so-far 1))
       ;; we didn't find one
       (funcall c c elt (rest tail) count-so-far)))))
```

And finally we can wrap this in a normal function definition, which we'll allow ourselves to use at the top-level:

```
(defun count-of (the-element list)
  ;; Count the-element in list
  ((lambda (f)
     ;; kick off the recursion: at the start the count of elements
     ;; seen so far is 0.
     (funcall f f the-element list 0))
   (lambda (c elt tail count-so-far)
     ;; Here:
     ;; - c is the function we must call to count the rest of the list
     ;;   (it's this function!);
     ;; - elt is the thing we are looking for;
     ;; - tail is the tail of the list we are searching;
     ;; - count-so-far is the count of elements found so far
     ;;
     (if (null tail)
         ;; we're done: count-so-far is the count
         count-so-far
       ;; There is more to do. eql is the appropriate 'is this the
       ;; same as that' predicate in this case.
       (if (eql elt (first tail))
           ;; we've found one, so we need to recurse with the count
           ;; being one more
           (funcall c c elt (rest tail) (+ count-so-far 1))
         ;; we didn't find one
       (funcall c c elt (rest tail) count-so-far))))))
```

There are some simplifications you can make to this: the recursive function can just rely on the bindings made in the outer function, and we can turn the recursive call slightly inside out:

```
(defun count-of (the-element list)
  ;; Count the-element in list
  ((lambda (f)
     ;; kick off the recursion: at the start the count of elements
     ;; seen so far is 0.
     (funcall f f list 0))
   (lambda (c tail count-so-far)
     ;; Here:
     ;; - c is the function we must call to count the rest of the list
     ;;   (it's this function)l
     ;; - tail is the tail of the list we are searching;
     ;; - count-so-far is the count of elements found so far
     ;;
     (if (null tail)
         ;; we're done: count-so-far is the count
         count-so-far
       ;; There is more to do. eql is the appropriate 'is this the
       ;; same as that' predicate in this case.
       (funcall c c (rest tail)
                (+ count-so-far (if (eql the-element (first tail)) 1 0)))))))
```

This is not really an improvement however: it's just a bit shorter.

And we can see this work:

```
> (count-of 'a '(1 2 3 4 a (a a a) a 5))
2

> (count-of 'a '(1 2 3 4 (a a a) a 5))
1

> (count-of 'a '(1 2 3 4 (a a a) 5))
0
```

---

For added value here is a version of the last version above in a language which is a Lisp-1, so we don't need `funcall`.  This is [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/):

```
(define count-of
  (λ (the-element lst)
    ((λ (f)
       (f f lst 0))
     (λ (c tail count-so-far)
       (if (null? tail)
           count-so-far
           (c c (rest tail)
              (+ count-so-far (if (eqv? the-element (first tail)) 1 0))))))))
```